# Flags to save battery life in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, battery-life

I'm wondering what flags could be switched on/off in Chrome to make it save more battery life.

Comment: It's clear to me what the question is: the OP wants to know what experimental flags (under chrome://flags) can be adjusted to reduce Chrome's power consumption.